# Redirect to a folder located on laravel installation folder

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I have installed wordpress on a sub folder (sricargo-blog) inside the laravel installation folder. I want to redirect to that wordpress folder(admin panel of wordpress) when user click on `/wp-blog` url. I get this 404 page not found error everytime I go to that url.

This is the directory structure

- sricargo

  - app
  - bootstrap
  - config
  - database
  - public
  - resources
  - **sricargo-blog**
  - storage
  - tests 
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
    Other laravel files

This is my route in web.php

```
Route::get('/wp-blog', function () {
return Redirect::to('sricargo-blog');
});
```

.htaccess file in public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /../sricargo-blog/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

What am i doing wrong ? Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: After you have rewritten everything that does not match an existing file or folder to the index.php with the lines following `# Handle Front Controller...`, you can’t expect the same thing to happen again in the lines below that. If anything, you need to do this the other way around - more specific rewrites first, more general ones later. But I really doubt whether this kind of setup makes sense to begin with, I’d expect that could cause other routing-related issues as well.

Comment: move `sricargo-blog` folder to your public directory,  the it will be accessible directly by `domain.com/sricargo-blog`

Comment: Anything available `public`ly should go to Laravel's `public` folder

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do it using .htaccess, no need to give route in laravel.
In your .htaccess file put this code.

```
RewriteEngine On

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /wp-blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /../sricargo-blog/index.php/$1 [L]
```